# Why I'm getting only part of data from XML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this script:

```
<?php
$map_url = 'http://example.com/data.xml';
if (($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($map_url)) === false) {
    echo "Error fetching XML\n";
} else {
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
   if (!$data) {
       echo "Error loading XML\n";
       foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
           echo "\t", $error->message;
       }
    } else {
        echo $data->offer->offerName;
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo $data->offer->links->link['href'];
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo $data->offer->thumbnail['image'];
    }
}
?>
```

It loads the contents from the XML similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Result xmlns="urn:buscape"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/admin/lomadee.xsd">
    <offer categoryId="2493" id="104951929015047">
        <offerName>BIQUINI BASICO AVELA</offerName>
        <links>
            <link url="http://example.com/hello" type="offer"/>
        </links>
        <thumbnail url="http://example.com/hello.jpg"/>
        <price>
        ...
```

I need to get the contents from the tables:

```
<offerName>
<link>
<thumbnail>
```

But I'm only being able to get the content from `<offerName>`. In other words, I need to get the title, image and link, but I'm only getting the title.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't loop through the elements, but according to your comments, that's your intention. In order to do it, do a `foreach` on `$data->offer`.

What's `$data->offer->thumbnail['image']`? I don't see any `image` in `thumbnail` element, only a `url` attribute. If you want to get an attribute from an element, use `attributes()` like this:

```
$offer->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;
```

As for the links, there is no way for SimpleXML to know which one of the links are you accessing (and it's not expected to know that there is only one element). Use array indexes to access different elements:

```
$offer->links[0]->link[0];
```

or if you want specifically the URI:

```
$offer->links[0]->link[0]->attributes()->url;
```

Final code:

```
foreach($data->offer as $offer)
{
    $title = (string)$offer->offerName;
    $thumbnail = $offer->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;
    $uri = $offer->links[0]->link[0]->attributes()->url;
}
```

Comment: $data is the main table from the xml, it's called "Result", then the array sequence comes like this:
<offer> -- > <thumbnail>
-----
You can see the xml here:
http://bws.buscape.com/service/offers/lomadee/65717751673178504d42633d/BR/?sourceId=28400481&advertiserId=5889&page=1

Comment: The thumbnail worked, but the link didn't. By the way, why does it only display a single result?

Comment: @user3692451: I edited my answer. As for the fact that you see the first result only, this is because you never loop through the elements in your code.

Comment: I used `echo "$title";` Still I could only get the title.
Ah, and I'm trying to create an image from the thumbnail expression, but it looks like it is not closing properly.

`echo "<img src=\"  . $data->offer->thumbnail->attributes()->url . \"/>";
`

Comment: @user3692451: the piece of code from your comment has nothing to do with my answer. Are you sure you've read it after it was edited 20 minutes ago?

Comment: I'm almost finished, all the data I wanted to retrieve worked, thx to you. Now I'm only working on Css stuff. Do you want to take credits for what you have helped me with? I'm going to write a blog post and I wonder if you want me to include your website on it. If so, tell me how I can contact you.

Comment: @user3692451: you're welcome. The content on Stack Exchange is licensed under Creative Commons; this article explains in four points the [attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) aspect.